# How to track a Registration Form fields

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, event-tracking

How to track a Registration Form fields.

I have a "registration form" in my website. As usual we have common field like name, email id, address etc. Along with these we have two fileds which will have drop down menu to differentiate the users. 
One Field name is Industry Type, this will have drop down menu like Health Care, Retail, Restaurants etc
Another one is User Type, this will have drop down menu like Merchant, Retails etc...

And all these users will have the same page after login.

Now i need to pass the Industry Type and User Type values to Analytics which the user selected while regestering.

Answer (score 0):

### Custom dimensions

In Google Analytics -> Tab Administration -> Tab Property -> Tab Custom Definitions -> Custom Dimensions

Create New Industry Type

- Scope User
- ID 1

Create New User Type

- Scope User
- ID 2

### Tracking Code

```
ga("set","dimension1","Heavy Industry");
ga("set","dimension2","Super Customer");
```

OR

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Registration', 'New Member', {
  'dimension1': "Heavy Industry",
  'dimension2':'Super Customer'
});
```

OR TagManager

Create two dataLayer macros for industryType and userType

```
dataLayer.push({
                    'eventCategory':'Registration',
                    'eventAction':'New Member',
                    'industryType':'Heavy Industry',
                    'userType':'Super Customer',
                    'event':'fire'
                });
```